# Criteria Based Sharing Rule In Apex Test Class

Tags: community

Do criteria based sharing rules execute when we create records in apex test class? I am facing a wierd issue. In my test class, have created account and contact records and they are successfully getting shared with community users. When I create custom object records, they are not getting shared with community users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to salesforce Salesforce documentation
[Criteria based sharing rules help](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_sharing_cbs_about.htm&language=en)

`You can’t use Apex to create criteria-based sharing rules. Also, criteria-based sharing cannot be tested using Apex.`

I would guess that Account and Contact are shared through method different from Criteria based sharing rules.

Comment: The sharing rule seems to be working for account and contact records. Created 10 contact records and all of them successfully got shared to the community user I inserted in apex test class.

Comment: My bad. The account and contacts are shared using owner based sharing rules and not criteria based. Hence it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you set any object OWD as private and create sharing rule, In back end salesforce create a objet named as objectname__share. This object contain fields like which record(ParentId) share with which user(UserOrGroupId) and what are the permission like read, read write(AccessLevel).

You can create these share records in your test class than you will be able to share record without sharing rule.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example application of @amitchaudhary's excellent answer

**Test class**

```
class MyTestClass {
  @IsTest static void doTest() {
    // Given some mocked data
    Account a = new Account(RecordtypeId = someBusinessUnitRecordtypeId);
    insert a;

    // Given an existing org user with Profile = Minimum Access - Salesforce
    // and criteria-based sharing rules granting r/w access to Accounts of
    // recordtypes of particular business units
    User restrictedUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE ... LIMIT 1];

    // Given a simulation of the criteria-based sharing which is otherwise not honored in testmethods 
    SObject[] userShares = new List<SObject> {
            new AccountShare(AccountAccessLevel = 'Edit',
                    AccountId = a.Id,
                    OpportunityAccessLevel = 'Read',
                    RowCause = 'Manual',
                    UserOrGroupId = restrictedU.Id
                    ),
            ... other xxxShare as needed
            )
    };
    insert userShares;

   // when run as restricted user and code-under-test invoked
   System.runAs(restrictedU) {
      new MyClass.doStuff(a.Id);
   }
   // then assert ....
}
```

**Code-under-test (note inherited sharing)**

```
public inherited sharing MyClass {
  public void doStuff(Id acctId) {
     ... some DML that depends on running user having visibility into the accountId 
  }
}
```